# AJAX spreadsheet editor interfaced to own website

Tags: web-development, wysiwyg, table

My website has records that are tables. I would like for my users to be able to edit these records in an easy way. Currently they download a .csv-file, edit it in their favourite spreadsheet, and upload it again.

But this often fails (they upload in wrong format or edit fields that they are not supposed to touch). I would therefore like to present the users with an editor directly on the website.

So just like you can have WYSIWYG editors in CMSes for text I would like to have it for spreadsheets.

One solution would be to interface my website with GoogleDoc and have the users edit the files using GoogleDoc's spreadsheet, and some how get the sheet back when they are done, but I do not know if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dozen of jQuery plugin that can handle such a UI (short list with a quick search on Google).

- http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet
- http://reclinejs.com/demos/multiview/

But you can also provide your own interface using [Create JS](http://createjs.org/demo/hallo/) for example